# How to define and send variable?

Tags: sencha-touch-2

im new with Sencha Touch 2 and i have a problem working with drupal, json, etc...

It's simple but i can't take the solution.

I have a list who is completed by a json. This json comes from Drupal7 views in json format.

In my view i have something like that:

```
var listaArtistas = {
        xtype: 'list',
        title: 'Artistas',
        height: 240,
        store: {
            autoLoad: true,
            fields: ['node'],
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: 'http://localhost/json-artistas',

                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    rootProperty: 'nodes'
                }
            }
        },
        listeners: {
            itemtap: function(lista,index,target,record,e,eOpts)
            {

                var artistDetail = new Ext.create('app.view.ArtistDetail');

                panelHomeNav.push(artistDetail);

            }
        },

        itemTpl: tpl

        };
```

This code Works for me. And complete de list with the artist.

Now i click in the artist and goes to another view (artistDetail). But to show propertly this list with details of the artist, need the ID of the artist who i cliked before.

I need something like this in artistDetail.... url: 'http://localhost/json-artistasDetail'+NID, where the NID is the ID of the artist who is in the list before.

I don't know how to pass this parameters between 2 views in Sencha

Thanks for help... or read :D

Comment: May I also suggest you set a title that better corresponds to your actual question...

Comment: Done !! Thx.. is my firt time in stack

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many options are possible, here is one: after creating the detail view, you could set a dedicated property, as an example:

```
var artistDetail = new Ext.create('app.view.ArtistDetail');
artistDetail.setArtistID(artistID);
panelHomeNav.push(artistDetail);
```

Comment: And in ArtistDetail, write... ArtistID: this.getArtistID, ??

Comment: ArtistID: '' is enough to initialize it and have the getter/setter.  In the panel code, use getArtistID to know which artist to render.

Comment: Hi Gaëtan, im trying getArtistID but i can't... setArtistID works perfect but i don't know where and how use the getter. You have some example ? Thx

Comment: Not sure to understand but something like artistDetail.getArtistID() and/or this.getArtistID() or even this.ArtistID should work, shouldn't it?